# Error: Program type already present: org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

When I build my app, I get the following error: Program type already present:org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.
1:30 AM Gradle sync failed (6s 290ms)

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ercess.ercess_app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation group: 'com.android.support', name: 'design', version: '28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.2'

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4-alpha1'

    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
}
```

Comment: what version of the android gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Gradle version 4.4
Android Plugin Version 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error from D8 because the runtime classpath contains multiple definitions for org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.

On how to fix it check out the answer on issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77499230

> Sync your project in Android Studio, go Navigate -> Class, make sure "Include non-project classes" checkbox is selected, and type "org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier". Android Studio should show you jars that contain contain this type. If you are familiar with excluding transitive dependencies, excluding one of Maven dependencies that contain org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier should fix your issue.

Where in your case instead of org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier use org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.